# How to stop Ubuntu from launching the Atom editor at startup?

Tags: startup, startup-applications, atom

I don't see Atom in the application "Startup applications", also not when I do in bash:

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

But yet Atom always starts after booting.

Comment: Does `grep -i 'atom' ~/.profile` show you anything ?

Comment: There's not a lot of room for wiggle here, either it's being called from some script / command in startup applications or `~/.profile`

Comment: - New problem: Now both above commands don't work anymore. There is no reaction after pressing enter. Strange. Also after rebooting several times. Rebooting still brings up the atom application at startup

Comment: - Opened .profile with gedit and there was no mention of atom. Also a search in nautilus in the /etc/xdg/autostart/ for "atom" didn't give any results. :(   I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: `~./profile` is not a command, it's a file that is used to set up environment upon login.  look into `~/.config/autostart`  directory. Nothing there ? Do `grep -iR 'atom' ~/.config/autostart ` and `grep -iR 'atom' /etc/xdg/autostart`

Comment: Thanks @Serge, that grep -iR 'atom' resulted in me finding autostart=true inside /.config/autostart/gedit.desktop and I changed the true to false. Solved !

Answer (score 0):

As I have mentioned in the comments, there's not a lot of room for wiggle here, either it's being called from some script / command in startup applications or `~/.profile`

`grep -iR 'atom' ~/.config/autostart` and `grep -iR 'atom' /etc/xdg/autostart` are two commands that can reveal where `atom` is being called

Comment: He mentions it is not in Startup Applications :)